# RTD Client in C#

Tags: excel, interop, rtd

I'm trying to write a simple RTD client to start with something, but I seem not able to make the initial connection. I have found some examples on the web, and best seemed to be [this RTD client in C# gist](https://gist.github.com/bsommardahl/8605208).

Having this on MS-Excel: `=RTD("rtdtrading.rtdserver",, "WINZ20_F_0", "HOR")` - formula works on Excel and pulls fresh data.

In the code from the gist above, I then tried to instantiate the object with:

`var handler = new RtdClient("rtdtrading.rtdserver");`

So far, so good. But then, when I try to

`var valList = handler.GetValue(new object[] { "WINZ20_G_0", "HOR" });`

I get a big *Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))* from `IRtdServer.ConnectData(Int32 topicId, Object[]& parameters, Boolean& newValue)`, [line 24 in the code above](https://gist.github.com/bsommardahl/8605208#file-gistfile1-txt-L24).

If I try to use `new string[] { "WINZ20_G_0", "HOR" });`, then the error changes to *Specified array was not of the expected type*, happening a bit deeper, but I believe still before `ConnectData()` is actually run, as the call stack suggestes:

```
at System.StubHelpers.MngdSafeArrayMarshaler.ConvertSpaceToNative(IntPtr pMarshalState, Object& pManagedHome, IntPtr pNativeHome)
at ProfitRTDAnalyzer.Program.IRtdServer.ConnectData(Int32 topicId, Object[]& parameters, Boolean& newValue)
```

I can't seem to properly identify how to handle this. Changing the `object[]` refs to `string[]` where they relate to those arguments (the topic list), didn't help either (still _array was not of expected type).

According to [MS documentation, ConnectData() receives as second parameter a single-dimensional array of strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.irtdserver.connectdata), so I don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve this problem, I have done that:

1. Create a new class to implement UpdateEvent:

```
    public class UpdateEvent : IRTDUpdateEvent
    {
        public long Count { get; set; }
        public int HeartbeatInterval { get; set; }

        public UpdateEvent()
        {
            // Do not call the RTD Heartbeat()
            // method.
            HeartbeatInterval = -1;
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        public void UpdateNotify()
        {
            Count++;
        }
    }
```

2. and then, replace it into GetRtdServer function

```
        IRtdServer GetRtdServer() {
            if (_rtdServer == null) {
                Type rtd = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(_rtdProgId);
                _rtdServer = (IRtdServer) Activator.CreateInstance(rtd);

                // Create the updateEvent.
                UpdateEvent updateEvent = new UpdateEvent();
                _rtdServer.ServerStart(updateEvent);

            }
            return _rtdServer;
        }
```

Comment: I didn't really try your answer, my Office registration is already gone and I am not sure what I was trying to use this for... But your answer looks congruent with another in the gist (basically calling `.ServerStart()` with an instance/stub of `UpdateEvent` object. Give or take, your direction, if not solving it, makes sense and should help others facing the same issue.

Comment: It's not working for me:


`Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Access violation at address 000000000312E77E in module 'profitchart.exe'. Read of address 0000000000000008
   at IRtdServer.RefreshData(Int32& topicCount)
   at RtdClient.GetValue(Object[] args) in Program.cs:line 47`

47 line is `var refresh = rtdServer.RefreshData(topicCount);`

Comment: Hi Alexsandro, as we can see in the error description, this error looks like to being generared by profitchart. Even though, this question was asked 3 years ago, and can be outdated depending of the software versions you are using

Comment: Hi Paulo, I'm looking for RTD Client to read feeds from Tryd Application.